# Tab bar icons too dark

Tags: objective-c

My tab bar icons are too dark.

I tried setting the image for unselected to a more transparent image, but it doesn't make any difference. Even if I use a lighter image for the tab bar image, it doesn't change the way the unselected or selected images in the tab bar look.

How can I make the icons brighter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Note -** change color as per your requirement

```
 //for selected icons
 [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

 //for unselected icons
 [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

Comment: that's the title, not the images.

Comment: `[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];`

Comment: `[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];`

Comment: doesnt work. sets whole things tint color. I am looking for something very specific. Unselected image color.